# flutter pub outdated for a specific package?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run

```
flutter pub outdated
```

it gives me a list of all the packages I have in `pubspec.yaml` which are outdated. What if I have more than 100 packages in it, I'd like to know is there any command or way (except searching in terminal) to find out the information provided by above command but only for that package, something like:

```
flutter pub outdated xyz
```

where xyz is my package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android Studio and IntelliJ, use [Flutter pub version checker](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12400-flutter-pub-version-checker)

For Visual Studio Code, use [Pubspec assist](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist)

Comment: Pubspec assist doesn't help here. only good for adding packages

Answer (score 1):

There is [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12693-flutter-enhancement-suite/) plugin for **Android Studio** called Flutter enhancement suite which automatically detects outdated packages and suggests updates for you inside `pubspec.yaml` file